How to use GoRouter.of(context).backButtonDispatcher.forget property in Flutter using GoRouter
I'm attempting to utilize the forgot property in backButtonDispatcher to disable the back button navigation on the web once the screen is popped. However, I have been unable to find a solution to implement this behavior. Any insights on how to achieve this?

What do you mean by "disable the back button navigation on the web". You cannot disable the back/forward button of chrome (or the web explorer you are using)
